# Reduce is not working for my equation

Tags: equation-solving

Can anybody help me?

```
Reduce[{Cos[Sqrt[w]]*Cosh[Sqrt[w]]*L == 1, w > 0}, w]
```

This procedure takes a long time and is not working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `Reduce[{Cos[Sqrt[w]]*Cosh[Sqrt[w]]*L == 1, w > 0} // TrigToExp, {w}]` indicates that `Reduce` cannot solve the (transformed) equation. It probably won't be able to solve your original one, either.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that a closed form solution should exist? Questions like this should always indicate why it is reasonable to expect a solution.

Answer (score 7):

One difficulty seems to have to do with the constant L. If you are willing to assign a value to this, you can solve numerically. For instance:

```
L = -0.1; NMinimize[(Cos[Sqrt[w]]*Cosh[Sqrt[w]]*L - 1)^2, w]
{0., {w -> 9.01751}}
```

Using this as a hint, we can try to use the Reduce command with both w and L as variables:

```
Reduce[{Cos[Sqrt[w]]*Cosh[Sqrt[w]]*L == 1, w > 0, L > 0}, {w, L}]
```

Now you get a nice answer!

Comment: This gives the same thing as solving for `L` (`Reduce[.., {L}]`).  The order matters. Using the variables in the order `Reduce[..., {L, w}]` is closer to OP's code, and it still runs for longer than I waited.

Answer (score 5):

[`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) shows the solution `{w, L}`

```
ContourPlot[Cos[Sqrt[w]]*Cosh[Sqrt[w]]*L == 1, {w, 0, 10}, {L,-5, 5},
  FrameLabel -> {w, L}]
```

[image]